# Azure: Application Insights. Are the ai.x.xx.x-buildxxxxx.js file required?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

After enabling Application Insights on my MVC web app I see that a file called ai.0.22.8-build00154.js was added to the /Scripts folder (however, it was not included to the .csproj).

In addition I do not see this file referenced anywhere in the project.
When I run the web app I do see data being sent to my Application Insights instance on Azure.

*** Question ***
Is this javascript file even required?

Note that I do have the script snippet at the end of the  section (per App. Insights documentation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This file is not required. It is included in case you decide to host Application Insights JS SDK yourself and not use the hosted version on CDN (http://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js). The snippet is referencing this version, so in case you decide to host AI JS SDK script yourself, you also need to update the snippet.
It is recommended that you are referencing the version on the CDN as this is the way to get all the latest updates automatically.

Comment: part of the content there is used by the application insights tools in VS to inject some initial javascript when you create a new project.  and at one point i believe it was also there to enable typescript/etc intellisense completion?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I believe it is required, it's the Nuget package. The filename you have up there seems to match up with the [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.JavaScript/0.22.8-build00154).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If this is indeed required, then why do I see data in my Application Insights? I mean, things are working. But I have not included nor referenced this .js file.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar You have probably included the JavaScript-Snippet from [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-javascript/#add-the-sdk-script-to-your-app-or-web-pages). This snippet loads the ai.js-file from azure which should be the same as in the Nuget-package, so it's right that Application Insights sends data without the package.